# What is the state-of-the-art asymptotics for convex optimization?

Tags: convex-optimization, asymptotics

I've got a convex program of the form:

Choose $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to minimize $vAv^T$ subject to $O(n)$ linear contraints (including $v \ge 0$).  $A$ is a square binary matrix.

What algorithm gives me the best asymptotic solution?

Comment: Your program is not convex unless $A$ is positive semidefinite, or at least $v^TAv \ge 0$ over all feasible $v$

Comment: @SashoNikolov : Thanks, I should have mentioned that one of my linear inequalities is $v \ge 0$, so the condition $v^T A v \ge 0$ is satisfied.

Comment: @GMB So, the number of inequalities is not $O(1)$, but rather $n+O(1)$?

Comment: @AustinBuchanan : Yes, sorry - I guess I have even more than that.  My linear inequalities are $0 \le v_i \le 1$ and $\sum_i v_i = k$, so I have $2n + 1$ in total.  My fault for expressing myself poorly in the OP.

Comment: how much precision do you want? in general, solutions can be irrational. if you are ok with a $1+\epsilon$ approximation and convergence rate $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, the Frank-Wolfe algorithm can be very efficient and is very simple. check Ken Clarkson's analysis: http://kenclarkson.org/sga/p.pdf. if you want faster convergence, you'd have to go for more sophisticated techniques

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful.  It would be neat if I could guarantee termination in any polynomial number of steps, but - looking at other convex optimization resources - I'm not so sure that's going to be feasible.  Quick question: when you say $(1+\epsilon)$ approximation, I assume you mean my answer $a \le (1 + \epsilon)opt$.  But if $opt = 0$, what does that mean for $a$?